# Extract "layers" from GRIB2 in R (rNOMADS)

Tags: r

I'm just getting started with GRIB and GRIB2, so forgive me if this is overly basic.

I have been unable to use ReadGrib because I can't determine a valid "layer" parameter (function requires layer parameter).  Using GribInfo doesn't seem to provide this information.  Opening the relevant GRIB2 file in Panoply offers me variable names, but not layers.

Is there another function or a wgrib2 native command that would give me a cleaner summary of the contents than GribInfo does?  Or is there a more direct way to find out valid layers?

Thanks for any help you can give.  I'll go answer a few questions I DO know the answers to now.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReadGrib is looking for a "level" parameter, and GribInfo will as well.  This will probably look something like

```
TMP:2 m above ground
```

Where TMP is temperature and 2 m abovd ground is level (what you are calling layer).  It would help to know the source of your grib2 file, or a direct link to it, to troubleshoot further.